Noisy headset on the bike front side
How to solve the issue with noisy headset on wilier GTR after tightening the headset. The front rim seems to be shakey. Please share some advice

Based on a quick search, you have a threadless steerer setup, correct?  Which bolts did you adjust, in what order, when tightening the headset already ?

Yes, thanks for the advice. I believe my hub is the problem causing the wobble and will get that replaced

Check out https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16936/could-i-have-damaged-the-bearings-cone-when-replacing-a-tire-front-wheel-wobble  and  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/how-do-i-know-if-my-cone-cap-bearings-need-to-be-adjusted   for info on bearing adjustment.  This might be a simple adjustment of the axle's nuts.

Start by isolating the problem to either the headset or the front wheel.

Stand beside the bike, hold the toptube in one hand and the top of the front wheel with the other.  Push and pull - there should be zero sideways play with the wheel relative to the fork/crown.   If there is sideways play, its likely in the bearings or a small chance the axle is broken, or maybe the whole wheel is not secured in the fork whether it be nuts, a quick-release skewer, or a through axle.

Test the headset next, by wrapping one hand around the top of the headtube where the steerer exits upward toward the handlebars.  Have forefinger and thumb wrapped around steerer tube, and the rest of hand touching the frame.With your other hand, squeeze the front brake lever to lock the brake up, and rock the bike backward and forward.  There should be no play between the two parts, or very very minimal.  Significant play here results in terrible handling and erratic braking.


If these two tests are satisfactory but steer, then I would guess your headset is worn or dirty or damaged or missing bearing balls, and would benefit from a teardown and clean/regrease.  If you feel this is beyond your comfort zone, then a Local Bike Shop would be the next step.
Your headset should allow the handlebars and front fork to turn left and right smoothly without high effort, but not be loose.  There should be no notchiness or gritty sensation.
